# Any Alternatives to Unions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm in the process of creating a query that will bring back all the data I need.

Here's my query:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime 
Set @StartDate = '2/1/2018'

Declare @EndDate datetime 
Set @EndDate = '4/5/2018'

Declare @UserID int
Set @UserId = '153056'

;with EntData as
(
select 
    distinct (Entity_ID), a.user_ID, c.User_OrganizationalUnitID 
from 
    ViewMgmt as a
    ViewConsole b on a.Role_ID = b.RoleID
    ViewUsers c on a.User_ID = c.UserID
where 
    b.RoleID in ( 53354666, 5363960) and 
    a.User_ID = @UserID  and
    a.Entity_ID <> 6912276036227
)

select a.User_ID, a.User_Name, a.UOName, 
    b.C_OID, c.OName,
    d.CID, e.Affected
from view.a
    inner join view_Cool.a1 on a.User_ID = a1.UserID and a.CI_D = a1.CID
    inner join view_New.b on a.CI_D = b.C_ID
    left join view_Large.c on b.C_OID = c.OID
    left join view_Small.d on a.CI_D = d.CID
    left join view_Old.e on d.Cert_ID = e.CI_D and a.User_ID = e.User_ID
    inner join EntData on b.C_OID = EntityData.Entity_ID
where ((a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate = a.ExpirationDate) 
    or (a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate is null)) and (a.UI <> 6912276036227 or a.UI <> 1414)
    and a1.IsHidden = 0 and a.UCS <> 13

UNION 

select a.User_ID, a.User_Name, a.UOName, 
    b.C_OID, c.OName,
    d.CID, e.Affected
from view.a
    inner join view_Cool.a1 on a.User_ID = a1.UserID and a.CI_D = a1.CID
    inner join view_New.b on a.CI_D = b.C_ID
    left join view_Large.c on b.C_OID = c.OID
    left join view_Small.d on a.CI_D = d.CID
    left join view_Old.e on d.Cert_ID = e.CI_D and a.User_ID = e.User_ID
    inner join EntData g on a.UI = g.OID
where ((a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate = a.ExpirationDate) 
    or (a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate is null)) and a.UI <> 6912276036227 
    and a.UI = 1414 
    and (c.OName like '%VXA%' or c.OName like '%Amazon%' or a.CI_D in (414,4561))
    and a1.Hidden = 0 and a.UCS <> 13
```

Originally, the first part of the union was all that I had, but someone wanted to see extra data SPECIFICALLY for one ID (a.UI = 1414). I didn't want to bring back more data for all the UI's in the system, so I made a union to bring back extra data specifically in one UI. The data that I want is coming back; however, now, instead of loading within a minute, the query can take upwards of 4 minutes to load (versus 30-40 seconds for the first SELECT statement). I've been wrestling with this code for a while now and I'm ready to get it working efficiently.

I was trying to think if there was a way to do that last join (inner join EntData g on a.UI = g.OID in the last part of the union, rather than having to tack on a completely separate SELECT statement) only when the UI equals 1414, but I don't think that's possible. I tried implementing that last join into the first SELECT, but it did not run. I'm still a novice with SQL, so any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why do you need `union` there? Remove it and ` or a.UI <> 1414` from first query. Result will be same if there were not duplicate rows

Comment: @uzi considering the OP is using `UNION` (and not `UNION ALL`) then duplicates don't come into it. `UNION` removes duplicates (where as `UNION ALL` does not, and hence why it's generally quicker; especially if duplicates don't matter, and been avoided another way).

Comment: @Larnu, I have noted about duplicates, Anyway, it seemed like conditions in where clause were identical, But i missed one. So my previous comment is wrong

Comment: @Gordon Linoff
How can I do that without posting the actual data? Thank you.

Comment: For the lines with `(a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate...` why do you have `...a.ExpirationDate = a.ExpirationDate`? Also, in the `OR` of that same block, you can just use `OR (a.ExpirationDate is null`. If it's `NULL`, it will never be between `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. There's no need to check that. `and a1.IsHidden = 0` should move up to the `inner join view_Cool.a1` > as other `JOIN` filters in the `WHERE`, unless needed to filter final results.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL? And approx how many rows are you working with? If it's a few million rows, 40 seconds may not be a problem. If it's a few hundred rows, there's a big problem.

Comment: It's only returning 800 rows.

Comment: @RustyShackleford   How many are in the table though? There may be several things you can do to speed up the query in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your joint queries are almost same. Try to join them and make one query from them. I think this query should return same result. But will include duplicate rows if there are.

```
select a.User_ID, a.User_Name, a.UOName, 
    b.C_OID, c.OName,
    d.CID, e.Affected
from view.a
    inner join view_Cool.a1 on a.User_ID = a1.UserID and a.CI_D = a1.CID
    inner join view_New.b on a.CI_D = b.C_ID
    left join view_Large.c on b.C_OID = c.OID
    left join view_Small.d on a.CI_D = d.CID
    left join view_Old.e on d.Cert_ID = e.CI_D and a.User_ID = e.User_ID
    inner join EntData on b.C_OID = EntityData.Entity_ID
where ((a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate = a.ExpirationDate) 
    or (a.ExpirationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and a.ExpirationDate is null)) and (a.UI <> 6912276036227)
    and a1.IsHidden = 0 and a.UCS <> 13

    and 1 = case 
                when a.UI = 1414 
                    case
                        when c.OName like '%VXA%' or c.OName like '%Amazon%' or a.CI_D in (414,4561) then 1
                        else 0 
                    end
                else 1
            end
```

Comment: So, this definitely speeds up the query, but I'm still missing data that contains c.OName like '%VXA%' or c.OName like '%Amazon%', which has to do with the final joins in both Select statements. I need 'EntData on b.C_OID = EntityData.Entity_ID', but 'inner join EntData g on a.UI = g.OID' for when UI = 1414. 




Is there some way to add a condition for joins?

Comment: Condition `c.OName like '%VXA%' or c.OName like '%Amazon%' or a.CI_D in (414,4561)` is applied to only `a.UI = 1414`.Does not it?

Answer (score 1):

I refactored and added some notes.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime 
  SET @StartDate = '2018-02-01'  --- Use ISO 8601 dates. YYYY-MM-DD
DECLARE @EndDate datetime 
  SET @EndDate = '2018-04-05'  --- Use ISO 8601 dates. YYYY-MM-DD
DECLARE @UserID int
  SET @UserId = 153056  --- Remove single quotes. You're assigning a string to an int. 

; WITH EntData AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Entity_ID , OID /* This needs to be included for later JOIN. Remove the other columns you don't use. */
    FROM ViewMgmt a  --- USE ANSI-92 syntax. Pretty please.
    INNER JOIN ViewConsole b on a.Role_ID = b.RoleID
        AND b.RoleID in ( 53354666, 5363960 )
    INNER JOIN ViewUsers c on a.User_ID = c.UserID
    WHERE  
        a.User_ID = @UserID  
        AND a.Entity_ID <> 6912276036227
)
, UnionedQueries AS ( -- Combine the common parts of the UNIONed queries into a second CTE for reuse.
    SELECT a.User_ID, a.User_Name, a.UOName
        , b.C_OID
        , c.OName
        , d.CID
        , e.Affected
        , a.UI  -- Added for UNION
        , a.CI_D -- Added for UNION
    FROM view.a a
    INNER JOIN view_Cool.a1 a2 ON a.User_ID = a1.UserID 
        AND a.CI_D = a1.CID
        AND a1.IsHidden = 0  --- Move this filter into the INNER JOIN. It will reduce the JOINed resultset.
    INNER JOIN view_New.b b ON a.CI_D = b.C_ID
        LEFT JOIN view_Large.c c ON b.C_OID = c.OID

    /* These JOINs are connecting across multiple tables. Make sure it's returning what you think it is how it should be. */
    LEFT JOIN view_Small.d d ON a.CI_D = d.CID 
    LEFT JOIN view_Old.e e ON d.Cert_ID = e.CI_D 
            AND a.User_ID = e.User_ID

    WHERE (
            ( a.ExpirationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ) /* ??? and a.ExpirationDate = a.ExpirationDate ??? Typo? What was this supposed to do? */ 
            OR 
            ( a.ExpirationDate IS NULL ) --If this is checking for NULL, it won't be BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
            --- These two conditions could be combined as ISNULL(a.ExpirationDate,@StartDate), but that is very micro-optimization.
        ) 
        and a.UI NOT IN ( 6912276036227, 1414 )  -- This is functionally the same as using two <>s, just easier to follow.
        and a.UCS <> 13
)
/* Now that the common query is already run, we can just use those results to get our final UNION */
SELECT u1.User_ID, u1.User_Name, u1.UOName, u1.C_OID, u1.OName, u1.CID, u1.Affected
FROM UnionedQueries u1
INNER JOIN EntData ON u1.C_OID = EntData.Entity_ID  -- This JOIN seems to be the only significant difference between the two queries.

UNION

SELECT u2.User_ID, u2.User_Name, u2.UOName, u2.C_OID, u2.OName, u2.CID, u2.Affected
FROM UnionedQueries u2
INNER JOIN EntData g on u2.UI = g.OID -- This JOIN seems to be the only significant difference between the two queries.
WHERE u2.UI = 1414 
    AND ( 
        u2.OName LIKE '%VXA%' 
        OR u2.OName LIKE '%Amazon%' 
        OR u2.CI_D IN ( 414,4561 )
    )
;
```

Note: This will need to be tested. I don't know how much data the `EntData` CTE filters the queries, so excluding it to the end may result in a much larger dataset in the main queries.